# using actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled in xml

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am writing this app and I seem to be calling actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) in every Activity I create. I'm wondering if there is a way to set this value in the styles.xml or theme.xml; rather than repeating the same line of code every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is you can declare in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".CurrentActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detailed_forecast"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.youpackage.name.appname.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

CurrentActivity is your activity that you are in and MainActivity is your previous activity